# How to import HTML into HTML without duplicate head & body tags? (no frameworks if possible)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm playing around with HTML (, JavaScript & CSS) & decided to try to import one HTML from one file  into another, the goal is that I can make several modules and just import them into an empty HTML page, so they together create a fully working & content filled HTML page.

I would prefer to use something similar to how scripts or style-sheets are imported:
(ignore the $ signs)
`$<script src="file.js"></script>`
OR
`$<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

**The problem is that the `$<html>, <head> & <body>` tags are inserted again, is there any good way to fix this?**

I have tried some methods: `$<object> & <embed>` &
`$<link rel="import" href="file.html">`
I don't want to use `$<iframe>` because I have heard that it's a security problem (yes, it's not relevant right now, but if I'm going to use this method later for real, then it will be important).

I am aware of other similar questions, like this:
[Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file) 
but most of the answers use external frameworks like JQuery or Angular which I don't want to use, I would prefer to use a pure HTML or/and JavaScript solution if possible.

Example code:

- File to import:

```html
<p>"The import is working"</p>
```

- Base file to import into:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Import code here (or in head if it for some reason is required) -->
  </body>

</html>
```

- Desired outcome:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>"The import is working"</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

- Actual outcome (with `$<object>` or `$<embed`>), (at least as the Firefox inspect-element tool shows it):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
      
  <body>
    <embed src="file.html">
  
      #Document <!-- I don't know what this means/function is, can someone explain? -->
      <html> <!-- Notice the double: html, head, meta & body -tags -->
        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
        </head>
        <body>
          <p>"The import is working"</p>
        </body>
      </html>
      
    </embed>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem with HTML Import?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file

Comment: I have found this JavaScript function: XMLHttpRequest(); 
* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest
* https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp
It seams like it could work, but I get blocked by the webb browsers CORS policy (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) & don't know how to avoid it properly (help?):
* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP, by making your file names with a .php extension and use PHP include:

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>
```

Read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do the same thing for some time and the only solution I've come up with involves some JavaScript. When you import HTML the  `#document` tag means it lives in the shadow DOM which is different than the one rendered (I think, I don't really understand this stuff). In any case, after importing, I ended up having to render the element and append it to the DOM.

```
<!-- Original HTML file -->
<html>

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p> 
        Hello from original HTML.
    </p>
    <link id="importLink" rel="import" href="/path/to/import.html">
</body>
<script src="/path/to/renderImport.js"></script>
</html>
```

I had the following code in my `renderImport.js` file:

```
// renderImport.js
function renderImport() {
    let importLink = document.getElementById("importLink");
    let importedElement = importLink.import.querySelector('#import');

    document.body.appendChild(document.importNode(importedElement, true));
}

renderImport();
```

And finally, `import.html`:

```
<!-- import.html -->
<p id="import">Hello from the imported file</p>
```

[Here it is in Chrome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSqT5.png) Though you might have to disable CORS.

Comment: Check the "XMLHttpRequest()" comment above. Maybe it can help you?

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular CDN in Head tag then import html using this code

```
<body ng-app="">
<ng-include src="'header.html'"></ng-include>
</body>
```

OR

```
<body ng-app="">
<header ng-include="'header.html'"></header>
</body>
```

Use you can change header to footer or content

Comment: Ok, but how has Angular solved this problem then?